# How to get input and output stream of an opened socket?

Tags: java, sockets

I want to know how to get input and output streams from an already opened socket by another program.

I have tried to create a socket with the port that I want to sniff but jvm returns an exception, saying that the port is already occupied

```
Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", "5555");
```

Comment: Not possible in pure Java. If you want to do packet capture, you have to rely on native libraries. Have a look at jpcap.

Comment: Socket is kind of resource which OS bind to your process likes other file-descriptors; So you cant share that with other process directly. Might be good to make a normal RPC to other process and bind created RCP with an Adaptor to your Socket to make other side read/write to it.